# How to format text (for example making text bold) in svn log messages?

Tags: svn, version-control, formatting, tortoisesvn, svncommit

How can one format text in `svn commit` log messages? Using `*text*` does not make the text bold, it shows `*` in message when I use `svn log`.

Answer (score 8):

**Subversion itself** considers the log message as plain text, so you cannot do it in such a way that any client will display your formatting.

The **TortoiseSVN** client does however *display* log message text between ‘*’s as bold (and ‘_’s as underlined and ‘^’s as italicised), as documented in [the manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-log).
But bear this in mind:

- This formatting is meaningless to Subversion itself; `svn log` will display plain text.
- Tortoise appears to do this only when the characters immediately next to the markup on the inside are letters.
- Tortoise displays the markup characters, whether or not it honours them.
- The bolding is fairly faint in many fonts.
- I have the impression that the commit-dialogue does not always immediately apply the markup, e.g. when pasting text.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** format commit-messages. Period

Comment: In tortoisesvn one CAN style commit messages

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html In this link it is written under **Commit Log Messages** headline.

Comment: @MrTux How can we style commit messages?

Comment: I used `*text*` but it did not make the text bold.

Comment: If I paste text copied from somewhere it between `*` marks it does not make them bold. But I write text in between `*` it works.